# why do we use vaccum command in PostgreSQL exactly?

Tags: postgresql

> `VACUUM`  reclaims     storage  occupied by deleted tuples.  In normal
>   PostgreSQL operation, tuples that are deleted or obsoleted by an update are
>          not  physically    removed  from their table; they remain present until a
>          `VACUUM` is done. Therefore it's necessary  to  do  VACUUM  periodically,
>          especially on frequently-updated tables.

This is what I got from man page. I want to know some cases where it is really required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `DELETE` rows or `UPDATE` them, then `VACUUM` is required to free the space for re-use. PostgreSQL usually does this automatically with autovacuum, so it is not common for you to need to manually run `VACUUM`.

You might manually run `VACUUM` after updating a large proportion of a table, especially if you're then going to do another big update.

Comment: can you help me in writing a shell script to use vaccu command ? thaks in advance

Comment: There's a `vacuumdb` shell wrapper. Use that. Or use `psql -c 'VACUUM ...'`.